# Reading Json file within a folder on Mac vs. Windows

Tags: python, json, configuration

Currently, I am trying to write an application that can be run on mac and windows. We have a folder with `PATH = "[folder1]\configurations\globals.json"`. The following function works for windows:

```
def grab_api_credentials(resource: str) -> dict:
    """
    :param resource: database, fmp, fred, polygon
    """
    with open(PATH, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    if resource is None:
        return data
    return data[resource]
```

How would you change the PATH variable to accommodate a mac?

To be sure, I have looked on many resources online, yet none of the showed how to read a json file within a folder. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: The only difference is that the Mac uses forward slash as the directory separator. Windows allows both forward and backward slash, so you could just use forward slash for both.

Comment: You can use forward slashes on both platforms, so `"[folder1]/configurations/globals.json"`. Is the "folder" part (that is the root of the file) also an issue?

Comment: You can also use the `pathlib`, which abstracts all of this away for you.